# How to retrieve TxPower of a bluetooth raspberry beacon?

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi3

I need to calculate the distance of a bluetooth device from a raspberry pi.
I am using below code -

```
def calculate_accuracy(txpower, rssi):
if rssi == 0:
    return -1
else:
    ratio = rssi/txpower
    if ratio < 1:
        return ratio**10
    else:
        return 0.89976 * ratio**7.7095 + 0.111
```

I am able to retrieve the rssi value but not the TxPower.
Does anyone know how to retrieve TxPower from a bluetooth device?
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What bluetooth library are you using? L.E: you seem to be using the code from the example in the link below. Note the last answer on the first page. https://python-forum.io/Thread-Python-Ble-Distance-Problem

Comment: yes that's right I am using the code from that link.